# How do I find the unfollow button on Instagram using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to find the XPath button in the picture below using selenium:

[image]

But because the XPath button on the top button changes every time, I decided to make a XPath for it:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@text=""]').click()
```

When running, my program gives an error that the xpath is invalid

I studied the xpath build methods well but could not find a solution for my program.

If you have a solution, write in the answers section

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an xpath to use:

```
//button[.//span[@aria-label='Following']]
```

It selects any button with the child span node with the aria-label attribute. This works on intagram because the dom looks like:

```
<span class="vBF20 _1OSdk">
  <button class="_5f5mN    -fzfL     _6VtSN     yZn4P   ">
    <div class="                     Igw0E   rBNOH          YBx95       _4EzTm                                                                                                              " style="height: 28px;">
      <span aria-label="Following" class="glyphsSpriteFriend_Follow u-__7">
      </span>
    </div>
  </button>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

`[@text=""]` predicate "presumes" that you want to select element with *attribute `text` with empty value* (`<button text="">button text</button>`).

If you want to select element with *empty text node* (`<button></button>`) try

```
'//button[text()=""]'
```